# changing the src of an image using javascript for a django website

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm creating a website using django. At the front end I want to change slides every x seconds. My approach was to change the src of the image every x seconds using javascript

Here's how I went about it:

```
//Javascript
function newSlide() {
    var imageTemplate = document.querySelector(".slide-img");
    setInterval({
    imageTemplate.setAttribute("src", "{% static 'images/newSlideImage.png' %}")
    }, x);
}


<!-- html -->
<img class="slide-img" src="image.png">
```

I thought this would change the image for me but it didn't work at all. When I checked my console, it said I couldn't load the file and returned 404 error. error: "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

However the initial image loaded perfectly despite using the same syntax {% %}

Comment: `{% static 'images/newSlideImage.png' %}` syntax works in html template only. If you are using it in a js file it wouldn't work.

Comment: How do I solve my problem then?

Answer (score 0):

use `newSlide` function in script tag like :

```
<script>
    function newSlide() {
     var imageTemplate = document.querySelector(".slide-img");
     setInterval({
     imageTemplate.setAttribute("src", "{% static 'images/newSlideImage.png' %}")
    }, x);
}
</script>
```